# How to automatically track the latest action in Redux DevTools (time travel debugging)

Tags: redux, redux-devtools, redux-devtools-extension

I was checking a particular action in the history of actions of Redux DevTools and now I can't find the button to stick back to the latest actions, so that if any other actions are dispatched, I always stay at the latest one instead of needing to manually click on the latest one to switch to it from the previously selected one.

Answer (score 22):

The solution was to just click on the manually selected action again to **deselect it** and after that Redux continued keeping me at the latest action.

Alternatively, if you "lost" the action you manually selected and are stuck at, just click on the latest action twice, so that the line with the action name, that you clicked, has the same `background-color` as other lines.

Comment: Thanks for that mate, worked like a charm. The authors of the Redux extension really need to improve the UX in this. Its weird to need to look for this in SO